# Building a web service with Perl

Tags: web-services, perl

I need to build a server-side application (tiny web service) for testing proposes. What are some [CPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPAN) modules and Perl libraries for implementing such task?

Comment: You should be a bit more specific about your goals. What should the app be able to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities

- `CGI` - if you like to do everything like in the olden days
- `CGI::Application` - a little more advanced

or you could use frameworks like

- `Catalyst`
- `Dancer`
- `Mojolicious`

It depends on your skills and aims what solution you should choose.

Answer (score 6):

Testing a tiny Web service with [Plack::Test](http://p3rl.org/Plack%3a%3aTest):

```
use Plack::Test;
use Test::More;
test_psgi(
    app => sub {
        my ($env) = @_;
        return [200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/plain'], ["Hello World"]],
    },
    client => sub {
        my ($cb) = @_;
        my $req  = HTTP::Request->new(GET => "http://localhost/hello");
        my $res  = $cb->($req);
        like $res->content, qr/Hello World/;
    },
);
done_testing;
```

Answer (score 5):

A web service simply returns a HTTP status code and some data, perhaps serialized in JSON or XML. You can use the `CGI` module to do this, *e.g.*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Pretty qw/:standard/;
use URI::Escape;

my $query = CGI->new;
my $jsonQueryValue = uri_unescape $query->param('helloWorld'); 

#  let's say that 'helloWorld' is a uri_escape()-ed POST variable 
#  that contains the JSON object { 'hello' : 'world' }

print header(-type => "application/json", -status => "200 OK");
print "$jsonQueryValue";
```

You can, of course, print an HTTP response with other status codes and data. A web service might need to return a 404 error, for example, depending on what's being asked for. That sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use [mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/). It's lightweight at first and can do the heavy lifting later too. [Mojolicious::Lite](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojolicious/Lite) in particular is good for quick and dirty.

```
  use Mojolicious::Lite;

  # Route with placeholder
  get '/:foo' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $foo  = $self->param('foo');
    $self->render(text => "Hello from $foo.");
  };

  # Start the Mojolicious command system
  app->start;
```